# How to make looping and input the way he wants it?

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I want to send to my friend but I'm confused about syntax from input and looping. Would you help me, please? Thank you:)

```
count = int(input_count("do you want me to say it again? how much : "))
count = int(0)
for hbd in range(count):
    print("━━━━━━━━━━━━Happy birthday━━━━━━━━━")                                                                                                
    print(" ( (  (   (   (    ( (        (   (( (         ( (   )   (    ( (  ")  
    print(" )\)\ )\  )\  )\  )\))\      ())  ))\)\  )\ )\ )\)\ (()  )\  )\))\ ")
    print("(_)(_)_()((_)((_)((_)(_)    (_)()((_)(_)((_)(_)_)(_))(_)(_()((_)(_) (  ")
    print("| || |   \ _ \ _ \ \ / /    | _ )_ _| _ \_   _| || |   \/   \ \ / / )\  ")
    print("| __ | - |  _/  _/\   /     | _ \| ||   / | | | __ | |) | - |\   / ((_) ")
    print("|_||_|_|_|_| |_|   |_|      |___/___|_|_\ |_| |_||_|___/|_|_| |_|   |/ ")
print("    ♥♥     ♥♥ ♥♥    ♥♥  ♥♥♥♥♥  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥ ♥♥♥♥♥♥  ")
print("    ♥♥     ♥♥  ♥♥  ♥♥  ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥ ")
print("    ♥  ♥  ♥♥   ♥♥♥♥   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥♥♥♥♥ ")
print("    ♥♥ ♥♥♥ ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥ ")
print("     ♥♥♥ ♥♥♥     ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥♥♥♥♥ ")
print("━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

Comment: you haven't asked a question. `count = int(0)` this line doesn't make sense, you ask the user for input and then set it to 0?!

Comment: Change this line `count = int(0)` to `count = int(count)`.

Comment: Just suppress the line count = int(0), or put it before the input line.
And you can use "input" instead of "input_count"

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code with suggested changes, it works for me:

```
count = int(input("do you want me to say it again? how much : "))

for hbd in range(count):
    print("━━━━━━━━━━━━Happy birthday━━━━━━━━━")                                                                                                
    print(" ( (  (   (   (    ( (        (   (( (         ( (   )   (    ( (  ")  
    print(" )\)\ )\  )\  )\  )\))\      ())  ))\)\  )\ )\ )\)\ (()  )\  )\))\ ")
    print("(_)(_)_()((_)((_)((_)(_)    (_)()((_)(_)((_)(_)_)(_))(_)(_()((_)(_) (  ")
    print("| || |   \ _ \ _ \ \ / /    | _ )_ _| _ \_   _| || |   \/   \ \ / / )\  ")
    print("| __ | - |  _/  _/\   /     | _ \| ||   / | | | __ | |) | - |\   / ((_) ")
    print("|_||_|_|_|_| |_|   |_|      |___/___|_|_\ |_| |_||_|___/|_|_| |_|   |/ ")
print("    ♥♥     ♥♥ ♥♥    ♥♥  ♥♥♥♥♥  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥ ♥♥♥♥♥♥  ")
print("    ♥♥     ♥♥  ♥♥  ♥♥  ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥ ")
print("    ♥  ♥  ♥♥   ♥♥♥♥   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥♥♥♥♥ ")
print("    ♥♥ ♥♥♥ ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥ ")
print("     ♥♥♥ ♥♥♥     ♥♥    ♥♥   ♥♥    ♥♥    ♥♥♥♥♥♥ ")
print("━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━")
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the seccond line .
it's going to work.

Goodluck.